# How can the same bash-function be known under multiple names?

Tags: bash, function, alias

We have several sizeable functions, which differ very little -- by one line.

I'd like to replace them all with a single function -- with that one line determined by `FUNCNAME`:

```sh
function single () {
    ....
    case $FUNCNAME in
    variant1)
        foo=meow
        ;;
    variant2)
        foo=woof
        ;;
    esac
    ....
}
```

The in-function code handling the different names is easy (see above). My problem is registering the same code (function body) under different names...

How can I make the same function known under different aliases? Simply using `alias variant1=single` is not working. For example, after the below code runs:

```sh
shopt -s expand_aliases
for v in variant1 variant2 ... variantN
do
     alias $v=single
done
```

the new variants remains unknown somehow -- even if `type -t variant1` correctly prints `alias`.

Comment: The problem with this approach is that aliases work via text substitution. `variant1` gets replaced with `single` before the command runs, so `$FUNCNAME` will still be `single`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The effect can be simulated with :

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

function single () {
    case $FUNCNAME in
    variant1)
        foo=meow
        ;;
    variant2)
        foo=woof
        ;;
    esac
    echo $foo
}   

for variant in variant1 variant2; do
    eval "$(declare -f single|perl -pe 's/single/'$variant'/ if ($. == 1)')"
done

unset -f single

variant1
# meow
variant2
# woof
```

Although the function code is duplicated and use of `eval` is not recommended for security reasons.

**Update 1**
Second method

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

single(){
    case ${FUNCNAME[1]} in
    variant1)
        foo=meow
        ;;
    variant2)
        foo=woof
        ;;
    esac
    echo $foo
}   

variant1(){ single "$@"; }
variant2(){ single "$@"; }

variant1
# meow
variant2
# woof
```

Comment: I'd replace use of `perl` with Bash's own facilities, but is interesting, thank you!

Comment: The second method -- using wrapper-functions and basing the decision on the next stack-level (`${FUNCNAME[1]}`) seems best to me, given Bash's (mis)treatment of aliases... Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I don't (personally) know of a way to give a function multiple names other than via an `alias`.

One (relatively) easy approach using an `alias` would be to pass in the name of the 'variant' as the first arg to the function call.  Then the first thing you do in the function is test the first argument as being one of the 'variant' names.

Consider:

```
func1 () {
case "$1" in
    func2) currFUNCNAME="func2"; shift      ;;  # shift remaining args into positions $1, $2 ... $n
    func3) currFUNCNAME="func3"; shift      ;;  # shift remaining args into positions $1, $2 ... $n
        *) currFUNCNAME="${FUNCNAME}"       ;;  # func1 called directly so $1 is not a known variant
esac
echo "currFUNCNAME = ${currFUNCNAME}"
}
```

Define a few variants:

```
alias func2='func1 func2'
alias func3='func1 func3'
```

Now some tests:

```
$ func1
currFUNCNAME = func1

$ func2
currFUNCNAME = func2

$ func3
currFUNCNAME = func3
```

---

Using OPs sample `shopt/for` code to dynamically create the functions:

```
shopt -s expand_aliases

for v in func2 func3
do
     alias "$v"="func1 $v"
done
```

Running our test again:

```
$ func1
currFUNCNAME = func1

$ func2
currFUNCNAME = func2

$ func3
currFUNCNAME = func3
```

Though at this point if the functions are going to be used in this script then why not edit the script to call the primary function with an extra input arg ... ?

Comment: Determining the name -- whether from `$1` or `$FUNCNAME` is easy. My problem is the aliasing...

Comment: i don't think aliasing (using `alias` at least) works inside of scripts

Comment: @MikhailT. please expand on what you mean by aliasing being a problem

Comment: @kevinnls `alias` works inside a script; care to expand on your comment (perhaps provide an example)?

Comment: @MikhailT. what is wrong with the 2 sample aliases in the answer?

Comment: @kevinnls, calling `shopt -s expand_aliases` is (or should be) sufficient to enable aliases in the scripts.

Comment: did not know. thank you @MikhailT. sorry, markp-fuso

Comment: @MikhailT. updated with your `shopt/for` code snippet; if this still doesn't address the issue ... what am I missing?

Comment: Actually, keying off of `$1` works. You're right, @markp-fuso. But the `FUNCNAME` remains `func1` even when called under an alias :( I suppose, I could make it work this way if there is nothing else (some clever use of `declare`, perhaps?)

Comment: the (obvious) problem arises from trying to override the value of the system variable `FUNCNAME` and my testing shows this isn't possible (ie, `FUNCNAME=somethingelse; echo $FUNCNAME` => prints the actual function name and not `'somethingelse'` ("Duh, Mark!" ?)

Comment: I'm not seeking to change `FUNCNAME` -- but I kind of expected, FUNCNAME to be the name of the alias, rather than of the function itself. Seems like it would make more sense. Sigh... The trick I attempted is commonly used: when the same executable is hard- (or soft-) linked under different names, the code can act differently depending on `argv[0]`.

Answer (score 0):

Another `alias` based option that relies on a user-defined variable (as opposed to a command line argument) ...

Assume our user-defined variable is named `$myalias`:

```
func1 () {

currFUNCNAME="${myalias:-${FUNCNAME}}"
echo "currFUNCNAME = ${currFUNCNAME}"

}
```

**NOTE**: obviously we need to pick a variable that we're sure isn't in use; from OP's comments it doesn't sound like this should be an issue (ie, just pick a new variable name that's not currently in use in the OP's script)

Define our aliases to first assign a value to `$myalias` and then call the primary function:

```
shopt -s expand_aliases

for v in func2 func3
do
     alias "$v"="myalias='$v'; func1"
done
```

Now some tests:

```
$ func1
currFUNCNAME = func1

$ func2
currFUNCNAME = func2

$ func3
currFUNCNAME = func3
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use aliases to define the new name to the same function

```sh
# attach a bash shell to a running docker container
function dexb {
    docker exec -it "$1" /bin/bash
}

# attach a sh shell to a running docker container
function dexs {
    docker exec -it "$1" /sh
}

# Now instead of creating another function say 'dex' with the same 
# content as the function 'dexb'

# I'll just create an alias

alias 'dex'='dexb'
```